# inlining font css files and fonts gone

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, requirejs

I have two css files for defining fonts. `font-awesome.css` and `open-sans.css`. In the `main.css` I import them like this:

```
@import url('../fonts/font-awesome/font-awesome.css');
@import url('../fonts/open-sans/open-sans.css');
```

This works fine. But if i want to inline these imports, (replace the imports with the file contents), (I am using r.js optimizer),  the fonts are gone. In the network tab they don't show up to be downloaded (namely the woff, eot files).

Actually `font-awesome` stays in place but only the `open-sans` font is gone.

Is there a problem with inlining font stylesheets, what is the proper approach to handling this issue.

**Edit**:
I have the project at [github](https://github.com/eguneys/marbles-site). The r.js configuration is inside `gulpfile.js`. You can see the relevant `cssOptimize` options in there. The style files are in `app/client/styles` folder.

To reproduce the problem run `gulp build` to build the project using the r.js. then run `node config/app` to run the server and visit `localhost:3000` to see the page.

Try this with and without inlining the font css files. You will see the `open-sans` font is gone when inlined. (comment/uncomment [this line](https://github.com/eguneys/marbles-site/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L152) to toggle inlining of the font files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>It's had to debug without source code.
It seems cause by wrong path in `open-sans.css`, there should be some 404 in network monitor. (but you said font resource never be loaded, strange ...)</del>

---

UPDATE:

Got the reason: when `r.js` minimize css file, it will remove the quotes, so the `url("OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#Open Sans Web")` will be compress into `url(OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#Open Sans Web)`. But there are some white spaces, without quotes, it will not take effect.

But the developer of `r.js` doesn't think it's a bug ([see this issue](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/527)), because white space should be escaped. (I'm not agree, may be `r.js` provide a config will be better)

There are my **three solutions**:

**1**. escape white spaces in `open-sans.css` manually, just replace `url(OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#Open Sans Web)` with `url(OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#Open%20Sans%20Web)`.

**2**. don't minimize css file, config `optimizeCss`, use `none` instead of `standard`.

**3**. rename font name (remove white spaces in it) into `OpenSansWeb`

I prefer first solution.

Comment: the `open-sans.css` file is ok. But the font is gone which is `open-sans.woff`. And this only happens when css is inlined. So it's not a path issue because path works fine if the css files are seperate.

Comment: In my understood (may be misunderstand): when you use @import & r.js, it will update path automatically for you: such as `open-sans.woff` to `../fonts/open-sans/open-sans.woff`. if you just copy the css code into `main.css`, `open-sans.woff` won't be found.

Comment: Yes you are right, the paths are updated, and `font-awesome.woff` is requested and served right. but `open-sans.woff` is not even requested. Who does make this request and how can i even debug this.

Comment: I suggest you diff your inline file with generate file by @import & r.js (which also compiled into inline file). `.woff`file not requested  may be cause by other problem (for example, it will request local font first).

Comment: can you provide `open-sans.css` and result css? I'm not quite your `inline` meaning, I thought `@import`+r.js -> final inline css

Comment: Yes you understand right, I also provided my project at github, see my edit please.